# Comparing two orthogonal decompositions of a Hilbert space simultaneously

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Let $T:D(T)\subseteq H_0\to H_1$ be a closed linear operator between the Hilbert spaces $H_0$ and $H_1$. Then we can decompose the Hilbert spaces as 
$$H_0=\text{ker}(T)\oplus\overline{\text{ran}}(T^*),\, H_1=\overline{\text{ran}}(T)\oplus\text{ker}(T^*)$$
respectively.

With these decompositions in mind, suppose that both $H_0$ and $H_1$ coincide, that is, suppose $H_1=H_0=:H$, and regard in particular the decomposition
$$\color{red}{H=\overline{\text{ran}}(T)\oplus\text{ker}(T^*)}$$

Suppose also that $\overline{\text{ran}}(T)\subseteq\text{ker}(C)$, where $C:D(C)\subseteq H\to H$ is another closed linear operator. It then follows, computing that adjoint of $C$, that $H$ can also be decomposed as

$$\color{red}{H=\text{ker}(C)\oplus\overline{\text{ran}}(C^*)}.$$

**My question:** now compare $\color{red}{\text{these two}}$ decompositions of $H$ simultaneously. Since $\overline{\text{ran}}(T)\subseteq\text{ker}(C)$, **is it obvious** 
$\overline{\text{ran}}(C^*)\subseteq\text{ker}(T)$ follows? 'Obvious' here meaning that *by visual inspection alone*; is it enough to plug the outstanding inclusion chain when comparing the two decompositions? **Or, is there some calculation or construction one would need to do in order to properly establish the last inclusion?**

*My loose thinking is since $\overline{\text{ran}}(T)$ is contained in a potentially larger set, $\text{ker}(C)$, that in order to maintain both decompositions simultaneously, $\overline{\text{ran}}(C^*)$ needs to be contained in the potentially smaller $\text{ker}(T)$, thus yielding the last inclusion. So that, the direction the remaining inclusion should point in be obvious.*

Comment: It seems from the decompositions that you'd guess that $\overline{\text{ran}}(C^*)\subseteq\text{ker}(T^*)$ instead (and this would be true if $T$ is densely defined though not obvious from the decompositions). Was there a typo?

Comment: I overlooked to mention that $T$ is densely defined. How would this yield the remaining inclusion $\overline{\text{ran}}(C^*)\subseteq\text{ker}(T^*)$? I know that it ensures that $T^*$ is then also a linear operator.

Comment: No wait, I think I have it ...

Comment: $\overline{\text{ran}(T)}\subseteq\text{ker}(C)\implies\overline{\text{ran}(T)}^\perp\supseteq\text{ker}(C)^\perp\iff\text{ker}(T^*)\supseteq\overline{\text{ran}(C^*)}$ since $\overline{X}^\perp=X^\perp$ and $T,C$ closed. With regards to the need for $T$ to be densely defined, did you have something else in mind beside it ensuring that $T^*$ also be an operator?

Comment: This works, yes. I had an argument by hand in mind where you note that for $y \in D(T)$ and $x \in D(C^*)$ you have that $\langle T^*C^*x, y \rangle = \langle x, CTy \rangle = 0$ by assumption which lets you conclude that $T^*C^*x = 0$ as long as $D(T)$ is dense. At some point in proving your chain of inclusions I think you will need an argument like this one.

Comment: @RhysSteele, if you would be happy to type up your suggestion for those interested as an answer, I would be happy to accept it and give you the credit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to define $T^*$ as a single-valued operator we need to assume $T$ is densely defined so in this answer I add that assumption.

First notice that $\ker T^*$ is closed since $T^*$ is a closed operator. This means that it suffices to check that $\operatorname{Ran}T \subseteq \ker C$ implies that $\operatorname{Ran C^*} \subseteq \ker T^*$.

For this, fix $x \in D(C^*)$. Then for $y \in D(T)$, we have that $\langle T^* C^* x, y \rangle = \langle x, CTy \rangle = \langle x, 0 \rangle = 0$. Since $D(T)$ is dense, this implies that $T^*C^*x = 0$ which gives the desired result.